# How to override class that implements interface in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to add my custom function in Magento\Framework\Message\Manager file in core file its working perfectly but when i m try to override its not working
So , I want to know how to override class that implements interface in magento2

below file I need to override:

```
vendor/magento/framework/Message/Manager.php
```

Comment: you have to create custom module and used plugin folder in it.

Comment: how can i use plugin do you have any idea ..because i want to add my new custom function so @Jinesh

Comment: yes I know that but can you tell me which magento version you are using?

Comment: my magento version is 2.3.2, can you please help me  how can i override this  @Jinesh